# change string in variable in bash

Tags: string, bash

When I assign in a bash script

```
DATE=`date`
```

and

```
TODAY=${DATE:4:7}
```

then `TODAY` contains `"Jul 2 "` instead of `"Jul{2 spaces} "`.

So I want to change the first space in `$TODAY` into two spaces.
 How do I do that?
Or how can I avoid the first wrong assignment to `$TODAY`?

Comment: When I do it, `TODAY` contains `"Jul<space><space>2<space>"`.

Comment: Make sure yo put `$TODAY` in quotes when you echo it, if you don't want spaces to be collapsed.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want `Jul 2`, why not using `date` options?

```
$ date "+%b %-d"
Jul 2
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want current month followed by two spaces:

```
date +'%b  '
```

or, for the long name:

```
date +'%B  '
```

to assign the command to a variable just use $() operator like this:

```
DATE=$(date +'%b  ')
```

and print it like this

```
echo "$DATE is the current month, with more spaces\!"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Quoting is the key.
2. Use `$(...)` instead of backticks.

You'll find that spaces are preserved:

```
$ DATE="$(date)"
$ echo "${DATE}"
$ Tue Jul  2 11:43:21 GMT 2013
$ TODAY=${DATE:4:7}
$ echo "*${TODAY}*"
$ *Jul  2 *
```

Answer (score 1):

use the date params to format the date how you want

```
date "+%b %_d"
```

will pad the day with space giving the 2 spaces you are after